# Python. Переименование файлов из txt документа

Tags: python, python-3.x

Здравствуйте! Есть каталог в котором разное количество файлов(картинки) c неправильными названиями и текстовый документ в котором правильные названия и соответственно 1-я картинка в каталоге == 1-му названию в текстовом документе.
Как правильно переименовать все файлы в каталоге соотвественному текстовому документу?

При использовании `glob` возникает ошибка:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\ufeffБез назви \ Untitled\n.jpg' -> 'Без назви \ Untitled\n.jpg'

```
with open("names.txt", "r") as files:
    for file in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
        for line in files:
            os.rename(file, line + ".jpg")
```

Данные из документа:

```
Без названия \ Untitled
"Обычные ритмы" \ "Usual Rhythms"
Без названия \ Untitled
"Поляна" \ "Glade"
Без названия \ Untitled
"Голоса" \ "Voices"
"Оно" \ "It"
```

Comment: а что делать с дупликатами: `Без названия \ Untitled` - пропускать?

Comment: @MaxU Добавлять приставку (1) или 1

Comment: Т.е. в результате файлы должны называться: `Обычные ритмы \ Usual Rhythms.jpg`, `Обычные ритмы \ Usual Rhythms.jpg`, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, сохраните names.txt в кодировке utf-8 без BOM. Во-вторых, считанные из файла строки надо очистить от символа переноса строки:

```
delimiter = ' \\ '
names = dict(tuple(line.strip()
                       .replace('"', '')
                       .split(delimiter))
               for line in open('names.txt', encoding='utf-8')
               if line.count(delimiter) == 1)

for file in glob.glob('*.jpg'):
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
    if name in names:
        counter = 0
        while counter < 10:
            try:
                n = ' {}'.format(counter) if counter else ''
                os.rename(file, names[name] + n + ext)
            except FileExistsError:
                counter += 1
                continue
            else:
                break
```

Comment: Спасибо, но выкидывает ошибку:
`ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required`

Comment: Значит у вас в файле есть строка не соответствующая заданному формату.

Answer (score 1):

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\ufeffБез назви \ Untitled\n.jpg' -> 'Без назви \ Untitled\n.jpg'

`\ufeff`  это [BOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2), что неявно указывает на utf-8-sig кодировку текста в файле (кодировка из locale, используемая `open()` по умолчанию, вероятно является ascii-совместимой).

> 1-я картинка в каталоге == 1-му названию в текстовом документе.

Порядок файлов в списке `glob("*.jpg")` не определён. То есть *"1-ая картинка"* не ясно о каком файле говорит: в алфавитном порядке, в порядке создания/изменения, как-то ещё.

Дополнительно, файлы в папке имеют уникальные имена, поэтому не ясно к чему повторять строчку `Без названия`.

В данном случае можно в словарь загрузить имена, чтобы легко замены искать. Для этого можно использовать регулярное выражение, чтобы имена из строки достать:

```
import re

with open('names.txt', encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
    name = r'"?([^"\\]+)"?'  # name regex
    names = dict(re.match(fr'{name}\s+\\\s+{name}', line.strip()).groups()
                 for line in file)
```

Переименование файлов, для которых есть замена, удобно с помощью [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib)  выполнить:

```
from pathlib import Path

for path in Path().glob('*.jpg'):
    if path.stem in names:
        path.replace(names[path.stem] + path.suffix)
```

Если файл с новым именем уже существует, то он молча заменяется.

Answer (score 0):

Не понятно зачем у Вас повторяется "Без названия \ Untitled" если этим пренебречь, можно сделать таким образом:

```
import os

with open('names.txt', 'r') as f:
    all_names = [i.replace('\n', '.jpeg') for i in f]

names = os.listdir()
print(names)

for num, i in enumerate(names):
    os.rename(i, all_names[num])
```

Я не предусмотрел никаких проверок на количество файлов и имен в файле `*.txt`, думаю Вы с этим справитесь. Предпологается что вы запускаете скрипт из той директории, в которой находятся картинка, или указываете путь